# Regex to block more than 3 numbers in a string

Tags: regex

I am trying to block any strings that contain more than 3 numbers and prevent special characters. I have the special characters part down. I'm just missing the number part.

For example:

```
"Hello 1234" - Not Allowed
"Hello 123" - Allowed
```

I've tried the following:

```cpp
/^[!?., A-Za-z0-9]+$/ 

/((^[!?., A-Za-z]\d)([0-9]{3}+$))/

/^((\d){2}[a-zA-Z0-9,.!? ])*$/
```

The last one is the closest I got as it prevents any special characters and any numbers from being entered at all.

I've looked through previous posts, but am coming up short.

Edit for clarification

Essentially I'm trying to find a way to prevent customers from entering PII on a form. No submission should be allowed that contains more than 3 numbers in a string.

Hello1234 - Not allowed
12345 - Not allowed
1111 - not allowed

No where in the comment section when the user enters the string should there be more than 3 numbers in total.

Comment: More than 3 numbers in a row, or more than 3 numbers at all? Eg: Is `a12a34` allowed?

Comment: I only want to allow text and ,.?! and then 3 numbers max anywhere in the string. So H3LL0 123 would not be allowed

Comment: Right, I think it's all clear now =). I added an asnwer as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

About the patterns that you tried

- `^[!?., A-Za-z0-9]+$` The pattern matches 1+ times any of the listed, including 1 or more digits
- `((^[!?., A-Za-z]\d)([0-9]{3}+$))` If `{3}+` is supported, the pattern matches a single char from the character class, 1 digit followed by 3 digits
- `^((\d){2}[a-zA-Z0-9,.!? ])*$` The pattern repeats 0+ times matching 2 digits and 1 of the listed in the character class

---

You can use a negative lookahead if that is supported to assert not 4 digits in a row.

```
^(?!.*\d{4})[a-zA-Z0-9,.!? ]+$
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZAlwAe/1)

If there can not be 4 digits in total, but 0-3 occurrences:

```php
^[a-zA-Z,.!? ]*(?:\d[a-zA-Z,.!? ]*){0,3}$
```

*Explanation*

- `^` Start of string
- `[a-zA-Z,.!? ]*` Match 0+ times any of the listed (without a digit)
- `(?:\d[a-zA-Z,.!? ]*){0,3}` Repeat 0 - 3 times matching a single digit followed by optional listed chars (Again without a digit)
- `$` End of string

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T3nfUE/1)

If you don't want to match an empty string and a lookahead is supported:

```
^(?!$)[a-zA-Z,.!? ]*(?:\d[a-zA-Z,.!? ]*){0,3}$
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1Vw8FT/1)

Comment: How would this block "test123". I'm testing and it is still allowing that. So far this is working the best though!

Comment: @TristanNohrer The string `test123` conatins 3 digits, not more than 3 digits so it is valid.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I can't believe I missed that. Thank you so much for your help! I have marked you as best answer

Answer (score 3):

Here is my two cents:

```
^(?!(.*\d){4})[A-Za-z ,.!?\d]+$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/PzRtTF/6)

---

- `^`  - Start string anchor.
- `(?!` - Open a negative lookahead.

  - `(` - Open capture group.

    - `.*\d` - Match anything other than newline up to a digit.
    - `){4}` - Close capture group and match it 4 times.
  - `)` - Close negative lookahead.
- `[A-Za-z ,.!?\d]+` - 1+ Characters from specified class.
- `$` - End string anchor.

---

I think it should cover what you described.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean <= 3 digits, this may be a naive one but how about

`[ALLOWED_CHARS]*[0-9]?[ALLOWED_CHARS]*[0-9]?[ALLOWED_CHARS]*[0-9][ALLOWED_CHARS]*`?

Fill `[ALLOWED_CHARS]` to whatever you define is **not special character and nums**.